# How to install an app on a VM using Mean Stack

Tags: linux, node.js, azure, virtual-machine

I have created a VM with MEAN stack (using Bitnami Image) on Azure which is currently running. I've never used a VM before, however I have a fair few MEAN apps using cloud hosting and Github continuous deployment.

I'm confused and I'm a noob using command line tools. I've found the Bitnami folder with the index.html etc. by connecting through SSH. I have a ready built angular application that runs on my machine. How do I get it onto my VM and start it running? I understand this may be a fair few steps, after lots of reading I assume I upload it, stop the apache server, npm install the dependencies and restart the server? How do I even get my app onto the VM in the first place, let along get it running.

Even the slightest insight would be brilliant - I am quite out of my depth with VM's and only have a surface level understanding. If anyone could lead me in the right direction it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitnami developer here,

To upload your files, you can follow this guide:
https://wiki.bitnami.com/howto/How_to_connect_to_your_server?#Upload_your_files_with_SFTP

We follow this structure:

```
installdir/
     apps/
        conf/ apache files and certs
        htdocs/ public files
        scripts/ scripts to manage service
```

You can find more information in this guide:
https://wiki.bitnami.com/Infrastructure_Stacks/BitNami_MEAN_Stack_(MongoDB%2c_Express%2c_Angular%2c_Node.js)

I hope it helps,

David